# Collection not loaded if bean was loaded before as relation

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have the classes A, B and C. A has a property to B (manytoone) and B has a property to C (onetomany). The classes look like the following ones (shortend to the relevant properties):

```
class A {
    [...]
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkb", nullable = false)
    private B b;
    [...]
}

class B {
    [...]
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<C> cs;

    public Set<C> getCs() {
    return cs;
    }
    [...]
}

class C {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkb", nullable = false)
    private B b;
}
```

The problem is now that depending on the order in which i load As and Bs the collection of Cs in B doesn't work anymore:

```
// outputs correct count of Cs per B
List<B> bs = session.createCriteria(B.class).list();
for (B b : bs) {
  System.out.println(b.getCs().size());
}

// outputs always 0
List<A> as = session.createCriteria(A.class).list();
List<B> bs = session.createCriteria(B.class).list();
for (B b : bs) {
  System.out.println(b.getCs().size());
}
```

The following debugging i have already done:

- In the second code hibernate triggers no select statements to load Cs
- In the first code the returned Bs are of type B and the Set of Cs has type org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet
- In the second code the returned Bs are of type B_$$_javassist_58 and the Set of Cs has type java.util.HashSet

I am using Hibernate 3.8.3.

Comment: If you don't load A at all do the problem persists ? In the second code it's ok that B is of type "javassist" because it is a proxy but it's strange that your Set<C> is a HashSet if it was loaded by Hibernate.

Comment: If i don't load As the problem doesn't occur (this is the first code example). The problem only occurs if As were loaded before Bs.

Comment: What happens if you don't ask the size but instead do a foreach on b.getCs() and print some variable from your c instance ? (yes it's strange but you know, with Hibernate... :D)

Comment: I already tried that before using size(). The collection is empty and the foreach loop is not entered once :-(

Comment: You never intialise Set<C> cs as a HashSet yourself ?

Comment: I do in the constructor of B (which is needed if i create a new B and want to add Cs). But shouldn't hibernate set their own collections after the constructor as usual?

Comment: Yes he should but it's not done. Can you try the suggestions listed in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following actions :

1) Acces your B instances by A :

```
List<A> as = session.createCriteria(A.class).list();
for (A a : as) {
    for(C c : a.getB().getCs()){
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

2) Use this criteria for loading B :

```
List<B> bs = session.createCriteria(B.class).setFetchMode("cs", FetchMode.EAGER).list();
for (B b : bs) {
  System.out.println(b.getCs().size());
}
```

Edit : Do you think it's possible for your project to query your database in a different way ? For example, you could try this (using HQL) :

```
List<B> bs = getSession().createQuery("Select b From B b").list();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers but neither 1 nor 2 works for me. Both times the displayed size is still 0. I even tried to remove the initialization from the constructor but this leads to a NPE. So hibernate really doesn't set the collection. I cannot use HQL as the whole application is designed for criteria queries. Even though i tried it using your HQL but size is still 0.

Comment: What if you remove the lazy fetching of B in A ?

Comment: If i set FetchMode.EAGER then it works. But i think that i cannot use this as it would be too much overhead to load all Bs every time i load A.

Comment: Is it possible in your project to close the session after loading A and load B in another session ? I think your issue is related to hibernate session cache.

Comment: This would work but i cannot locate all locations there this could be needed (extremly generalized application) and i am sure that in some cases this would have side effects leading to further errors.

Comment: And with the use of FetchMode.JOIN which add less overhead ? (fetch with a join instead of make a new select)

Comment: FetchMode.EAGER didn't cause an extra select but also only a join. The problem is that the referenced tables are very complex (>100 fields) and this adds a massive overhead (database and network).